# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. error in Flutter after upgrading to 2.10 version

Tags: flutter, dart

I upgraded my flutter version to 2.10 and it is giving me this errror while compiling -

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
e: C:/Users/Hp/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/518a28e11257a17211a8fb8a5067b186/jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.5.2.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/Hp/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6168eafaded8ddacbc73df91bd758ffe/jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04-api.jar!/META-INF/window_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/Hp/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6c0671fbb7722afc42898b4178b11de7/jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.5.2.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-android.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/Hp/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/91667e970d35cee0f38e121291f325a1/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.31.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/Hp/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/af48bf569b5523ddd7a06285f676a1ca/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/Hp/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b560d76b568ab2e29107d94002f1a070/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.31.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/Hp/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/d0224631d7841d16cd3b5d2fab11c793/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/Hp/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/e0583c70716c2ce3cdb07beee79fcae0/jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04-api.jar!/META-INF/window-java_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
┌─ Flutter Fix ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                          │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then    │
│ update                                                                                          │
│ C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Programming\Flutter\flutter_application_notifications\android\build.gradle: │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                         │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

And I am being honest here, I never have experienced bug free upgradation in Flutter till now, except when they made little changes. Literally. Can someone tell me why is this happening and please give a solution for the above error.

Comment: If you did not change android folder, you can try delete android folder, then run 'flutter create .' This will recreate android folder with correct kotlin version. If you did change android folder, you need to upgrade kotlin version manually.

Answer (score 0):

**Just go to:**
your flutter app\android\build.gradle:

**and initialize**

ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

***That's it***

Comment: Done that already, still error.

Comment: Done that already, still error.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the ext.kotlin_version in your_flutter_app\android\build.gradle

From

> `ext.kotlin_version = 'old version'`

to

> `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'`

which is the last version.

and you can always see the last version of ext.kotlin_version from the link

```
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions
```